# How to resume with last played song in android media player via code?

Tags: android, service, media-player, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing one media player for playing music. It is working fine but when I destroy the application and start it again then it is starting  from beginning it is not resuming. I want to resume the song from current position in media player. Just like other music players i want my application to resume from the current song that was played before destroying the application.

Comment: store time of currently played song and when you start app then seek to that time

Comment: i can't get the current song ad also the list in which the songs belongs to..

Comment: so you need to store current song id and played time and list also

Comment: yes I want to save those three before destroying the application.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the desired result .saved the list,song position and id in shared preference during onDestroy() call of activity and retrieve them in Oncreate() call.Working perfectly now without any issue.